# POST form HTML with Bootstrap Dropdown

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

In the following code, I want to submit a form with a Bootstrap dropdown and submit the selected value as "username". I'm not sure where in the following code I should add 'name="username"'. When I add it in certain places, it does not get set properly.

```
    <form action="/login" method="POST">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
          Dropdown
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        </ul>
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
      </div>
    </form>
```

Below is an example of code that does exactly what I want it to. But for design purposes, I'd like the form to be in Bootstrap.

```
<form action="/login" method="POST">
  <select class="form-control" name="username">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the links in the list (the ones that currently link to the top of the page) with [radio buttons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio) and [labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label).

Comment: Is it not possible to do with dropdown? I would prefer not to use radio buttons and layer all options down the page.

Comment: @Peter — I said to replace the links, not the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

We can add radio buttons for every list item, each giving them a unique value and `name="username"`. Wrap the text of every list item into a `label` with a `for` tag that points to the `id` of the corresponding radio button.

After that, the only thing that is left to do is wrapping the dropdown label into a `span` with `id='userlabel'`, and use this script to change the label of the dropdown menu to the selected list item. This will give the user an idea of which item is currently selected:

```
$("input[name='username']").change(function(e){
     $("#usernamelabel").text($(this).val());
});
```

We can hide the radio buttons with

```
input[name='username']{
    display: none;
}
```

The resulting `html` will look like this:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form action="/login" method="POST">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
          <span id="usernamelabel">Select username</span>
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><input type="radio" id="username1" name="username" value="username1"><label for="username1">Username1</label></li>
          <li><input type="radio" id="username2" name="username" value="username2"><label for="username2">Username2</label></li>
          <li><input type="radio" id="username3" name="username" value="username3"><label for="username3">Username3</label></li>
        </ul>
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
      </div>
    </form>
    
    <style>
    input[name='username']{
    display: none;
    }
    </style>
    <script>
      $("input[name='username']").change(function(e){
          $("#usernamelabel").text($(this).val());
      });
    </script>
```